# How do I generate a random 4 digit number and store it as a variable in python?

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to make a guess the number game in Python, but I'm having trouble. Here is what I have so far:

```
import random
number = random.randit(1111,9999)
print(number)
```

But for some reason I get an `error` saying something about `random cannot be assigned to randit`.

Any help please?

Comment: it's `randint` not `randit`

Comment: Why do you set the lower limit at `1111`? Does `1047` (for example) not count as a 4-digit number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a typo. It's `random.randint()`.

Comment: Thank you, I feel so stupid

Answer (score 14):

```
import random
number = random.randint(1000,9999)
print(number)
```

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
import string
from random import choice
chars = string.digits
random =  ''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(4))
```

this will make a different 4 digit number every time you run it. if you want to make more digits just change the range.